# Can VisualVM profile Java 9 applications?

Tags: java, profiling, java-9, visualvm

Hello I am trying to optimise my application, I've had JProfiler installed for the last 2 weeks but the trial period is up and I can't afford the megabucks.

I want to use VisualVM but I can't get it to work.
I installed version 1.4 from their website but when I try and open my application for profiling it does nothing. (Other available processes do open, like the intellij ide)

The error reported is as follows:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected composite type for ThreadInfo
        at sun.management.ThreadInfoCompositeData.validateCompositeData(ThreadInfoCompositeData.java:372)
        at sun.management.ThreadInfoCompositeData.getInstance(ThreadInfoCompositeData.java:68)
        at java.lang.management.ThreadInfo.<init>(ThreadInfo.java:263)
        at java.lang.management.ThreadInfo.from(ThreadInfo.java:794)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$CompositeBuilderViaFrom.fromCompositeData(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:1018)
Caused: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Failed to invoke from(CompositeData)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.invalidObjectException(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:1457)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$CompositeBuilderViaFrom.fromCompositeData(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:1021)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$CompositeMapping.fromNonNullOpenValue(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:919)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$NonNullMXBeanMapping.fromOpenValue(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:133)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.fromOpenReturnValue(ConvertingMethod.java:131)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:168)
        at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:258)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getThreadInfo(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxSupport.isReadOnlyConnection(JmxSupport.java:126)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl.isTakeThreadDumpSupported(JmxModelImpl.java:369)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views.threads.ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.resolveThreads(ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.java:85)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views.threads.ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.supportsViewFor(ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.java:49)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views.threads.ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.supportsViewFor(ApplicationThreadsViewProvider.java:45)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceViewsManager.getViews(DataSourceViewsManager.java:136)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.openWindowAndAddView(DataSourceWindowManager.java:206)        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.access$000(DataSourceWindowManager.java:50)
        at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager$2.run(DataSourceWindowManager.java:117)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
        at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
        at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
```

It looks like something to do with incompatible Java types? My application was compiled and run with JDK9. I've noticed VisualVM isn't even included in the java download any more. Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a coinciding time, but on a different note. VisualVM for me, while it detects 10-ea or 9 as installed JDK versions, doesn't startup either. Though it could be a different issue altogether. But sharing in case you might know a solution to it. The message on pop-up reads -> *"Error starting VisualVM" .. You are running VisualVM using an unsupported Java version: 10*

Comment: Please see the bug and solution on github https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/34 . It seems this issue happens when VisualVM is started on a java version before 8u141

Comment: Aha, will give this a go thanks!

Comment: That's done the trick thanks!

Comment: https://visualvm.github.io/

Comment: This is a JMX interop issue, all the details in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8139870 .